# Bringing in a google form response to a sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Here is a copy of the sheets and form (form > go to live)

https://docs.google.com/a/ncsu.edu/spreadsheets/d/1mEz9mLEgP4Cfts2ZU6NwhNiL6xjWdFbt42RUj-RYbZw/edit?usp=sharing

So currently, I get responses in a different sheet. Ideally, I would get the response on the tracking sheet with the appropriate format for the dates. Additionally, I would like to keep the functionality of the tracking sheet which is to  be able add in items by hand and not through the form. I currently have a script in place which auto-inputs the current date as the two separate formats.

So I'm looking for a solution which either takes in form response to the sheet and appropriate cells (the first empty cell). Or I'm looking to create a script which onEdit which when the form sheet is edited, will fetch the new response and copy it over appropriately onto the tacking sheet.

I have tried googling answers.. But I think I may be a failure at it since I wasn't able to really find a solution for this particular problem. Thank you in advance for the help!

form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1AHSQrLkq3U7NJMvgWoH3lAygova7Mi4BaXHdROaaS2g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sheet isn't public

Comment: Should be public now, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script associated to [this form](https://docs.google.com/a/ousset.net/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfYn39e3Irl8Gqzwl0Pum7F-DZ55-b1I54BUXkavBXoJuy4zw/viewform) should do the trick.
All the explanations on how to use it are in the response sheet

Comment: So I tried copying over the script and replacing the id with the appropriate items, but I can't seem to get it to function.

Comment: did you set up the trigger?

Comment: I did, trigger on form submit

Comment: I added some more specific doc here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mvFyVhPMfYCreLFTrZxLpuTYz0puY5x6FY7uAf0Csz4/edit#gid=2

Comment: Mm, I'm fairly certain that's exactly what I did.. But I may be insane.

Comment: Ah, I take it back.. I copied the code into an inner function originally.. instead of having it outside and as 2 separate functions.. my bad.